# AndroidUpnpService cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: android, upnp

I am trying to integrate [Cling](http://4thline.org/projects/cling/core/manual/cling-core-manual.html#chapter.Android) into my android application but whatever I try it doesnt work, It keeps telling me that it is not recognized as a type. I dont know what I have to add as a library file to get this working. Has anyone succesfully used cling  on android.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the Cling library.

1. Download it here (you want 1.0): http://4thline.org/projects/download/
2. Copy the Cling core and Teleal common jars into your project (e.g. the lib directory)
3. Add the jars to the build path